# 2D ArrayList For DataBase Table

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, arraylist, jtable

I am currently stuck on a section of code. I have a database and would like to put the information into an arrayList. At a later stage this arrayList needs to be put into a JTable. At the moment I can get all the rows to print, however all the rows print as one line with all the information, instead of each row printing as its own row. Not sure if that makes sense, my code is below:

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> movies = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> movs = new ArrayList<String>();

       while(rs.next()){

           movs.add(rs.getString("movie_id"));
           movs.add(rs.getString("movie_name"));
           movs.add(rs.getString("description"));
           movies.add(movs);
           for(ArrayList<String> ls : movies) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls.toArray()));
           }
       }
```

Output is as follows:

[1, The Place Beyond The Pines, A motorcycle stunt rider (Gosling) turns to robbing banks as a way to provide for his ex-lover (Mendes) and their newborn child.], 2, Riddick, Betrayed by his own kind and left for dead on a sun-scorched planet, Riddick fights for survival against alien beasts and becomes more powerful than ever before.] ETCETC

[1, The Place Beyond The Pines, A motorcycle stunt rider (Gosling) turns to robbing banks as a way to provide for his ex-lover (Mendes) and their newborn child., 2, Riddick, Betrayed by his own kind and left for dead on a sun-scorched planet, Riddick fights for survival against alien beasts and becomes more powerful than ever before.]
ETC ETC 
for the next 22 lines(thats the number of rows in my table in access)

Other information:

Just repeats all the rows in one line. Furthermore if any tips can be given on the JTable front, that would be brilliant. I am not sure how to get the above(in code) column names and the aforementioned rows to be part of the JTable. Many thanks and apologies in advance for my noobery! :>

JTable code -

```
       JTable table = new JTable((TableModel) movies);
       JScrollPane spane = new JScrollPane(table);
       setContentPane(spane);
       setVisible(true);
```

PS: All of this is in an actionListener.

Comment: Look for Jtables here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always used the same list object to add the elements. simply move it in the loop

```
while(rs.next()){
   ArrayList<String> movs = new ArrayList<String>();

   movs.add(rs.getString("movie_id"));
   movs.add(rs.getString("movie_name"));
   movs.add(rs.getString("description"));
   movies.add(movs);
   for(ArrayList<String> ls : movies) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ls.toArray()));
   }
}
```

I would sugest creating a Movie class and store them in a list of Movies:

```
public class Movie
{
    private int id;
    private String movieName;
    private String description;

    //.. constructor


    //...getters and setters
}
```

loop:

```
ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

while (rs.next())
{
    Movie movie = new Movie();

    movie.setId(rs.getInt("movie_id"));
    movie.setMovieName(rs.getString("movie_name"));
    movie.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
    movies.add(movie);
}
```

**JTable:**

[Here a very good tutorial on JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Wow, that was pretty simple! I feel like a proper knob. Thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as stack allows me to(7 mins). How would I add this to a JTable btw?

Comment: i added a tutorial link